# creating precipitation grid

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, esri-grid-format, precipitation

I am trying to create a precipitation grid for my meteorologic model.

The problem is that, I do not know what are the things I should have for me to create the grid.

Can anyone tell me what are the requirements and how to run the process?

I am using ArcMap 10.1.

Comment: Why not use pre-existing data for Precipitation like WorldClim http://www.worldclim.org/ or the National Weather Service http://www.nws.noaa.gov/gis/ I really don't know how you'd go about making a precipitation grid without already having the data.

Comment: i have station points (rain gauges) with daily precipitation record with it. so, what I'm trying to achieve is to interpolate these data using computation method (I don't know what's the best method actually) so I may have a precipitation model. I', trying have a gridded precipitation model

Comment: Do you have the Spatial Analyst Extension?

Comment: yes I have. . .

Answer (score 1):

If you have point data from rain gages of known locations (which you indicated in a comment), you should be able to interpolate a surface. Which method of interpolation you use is up to you and there are lots of references for determining the best methods and the science/art of kriging (a more involved interpolation method). You can usually get a decent result from the IDW method which is easy to calculate so why not start there?

I'd recommend having your points in a Projected Coordinate System simply because raster processing seems to work better that way (in my opinion).

With IDW you would use your rainfall data as input
(Input points and a field with the data).
[IDW link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000006m000000.htm)
Using a default for cell size may work well if the gages are evenly dispersed but you can refine this and experiment with the power and search radius settings as well.

Here are some references on the subject of interpolation with precipitation data.
http://popups.ulg.ac.be/1780-4507/index.php?id=10003
http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc07/papers/papers/pap_1451.pdf